# Modify text file in VMDK

Tags: bash, sed

I need to modify a text file in the file system of a VMDK file for a deployable OVA file. I have seen that it is possible to find the string (a test string in the text file needing modification) and replace it in the VMDK using sed, however whenever I try to replace it, it seems to work, but then nothing actually changes in the file. Here is what I have tried:

```
sed -i 's/oldstring/newstring/g' file.vmdk
```

The `sha1sum` before and after are identical telling me the file has not been modified. Something gets goofed up though because I can no longer start the VM of that VMDK (its ok, its a test).

Does anyone have any programmatic suggestions here. I will be doing all of this in bash. If no one can suggest anything, I will move this question to servar fault or SuperUser and ask if anyone knows how to mount the VMDK (Without VMware-tools!!!) then edit the file directly with sed or via some other means.

Perhaps there is some way of doing a binary search or something for the string to replace.

Comment: Try this article: http://ramslack.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/mounting-vmdk-files-in-linux/

Comment: If it's a binary file, `sed` may be giving up at the first null byte. Try with Perl instead? `perl -pi -e 's/old/new/g' file`

Comment: Thank you. I have already read that article, but I am trying to do this through code first. That method in my opinion is not very clean. You jump through lots of hoops to get to the end result. If all else fails I will just use vmware-tools. I would prefer not to install it though as it adds a bunch of unnecessary extras.

Comment: No change with perl. I don't think its binary. Not really sure what the file format is exactly.

Comment: what does `file file.vmdk` report? Can you open the file in vim without getting weird results (don't save it!). Good luck.

Comment: this also might help you tell if you have a binary file `sed 's/[[:print:][:space:]][[:print:][:space:]]*//' file.vmdk  | tr -d '\012' | od -d`. YOu can search here for `od -d` to see how to interpret that output. Good luck.

Comment: I probably cannot open it since its huge. Its the entire guest OS in a flat file. Kinda like an image.

Comment: So I just tried. It took awhile, but finally opened. The beginning was some info about HDD geometry, but the rest is hieroglyphics. Well this confirms that sed is out of the picture.

Comment: Can you explain that code a little please?

Comment: it's just to strip away all [:print:]able or [:space:] chars, which in a normal txt will will leave just line-feed chars, which the `tr -d \012` will delete. Anything that is left will get sent thru the `od` utility which will display the octal values of any remaining chars that didn't get stripped out. Good luck.

Comment: No luck. Looks like I need a way to either mount this file (which I dont want to do) or actually edit the text file in binary. Problem is, it appears that the vmdk file is a compressed version of the flat vmdk file (aprox 300MB vs 1.2GB). Any remaining thoughts anyone? I really need to figure this out soon.

Comment: Does anyone know how vmdk files are compressed so I can decompress it and work on it in bash?

Comment: @Atomiklan, .vmdk is a plain text file. I think you are talking about -flat.vmdk which is the actual VM disk. I have edited many .vmdk files with `sed`. Are you sure you are working on .vmdk?

Comment: Sorry. Been out of the office all last week with food poisoning... I think the -flat.vmdk file is plain text. The .vmdk file has a little plain text at the very beginning (HDD info), but the rest is all special character type writing. When I try to output the flat file, its huge (300MB vs 1.2GB) so I don't want to use the flat file. We just apparently need to decompress edit and recompress the .vmdk

Comment: If what you're trying to do is put some unique identifier into a disk image that the virtual machine can use to distinguish itself, there is almost certainly some better way of doing it. Like, ..., say, encode something into the MAC address of a network adapter configured int the VM description. A script inside the VM can look at the MAC.  Or something else.  I can't believe there is no better way to pass a parameter into a VM than to try to interpolate it into the disk.